# Clicking on an image or label in PageObject

Tags: pageobjects

```
label(:enable_allchild, :id => 'colHeader-Status')
image(:enable_allchild, :src => 'image/selectAll.gif')
label(:enable_allchild, :text => "Enable")
```

Tried all three of these

```
enable_allchild_element.click
```

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: cannot click on element

Answer (score 0):

Is it definitely the image or label that receive the click that actually does something? I've had a similar issue before and it turned out that the click was actually received by the span or div (I forget) that the image and label were in.